# jquery treating numbers as strings

Tags: jquery

here is the jsfiddle of what I am trying to calculate. I dont dont know how to convert those strings into integers.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ygsrv/2/

and here is the code:

```
$('#get').click(function(){
    var priceProduct = 18.9
    var length = $("#awp_group_5 option:selected").text().replace(/cm$/, '');
    var width = $("#awp_group_4 option:selected").text().replace(/cm$/, '');
    var priceProduct2 = priceProduct + (width + length * 30 );
    alert(priceProduct2);

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `parseInt(yourStringHere);`

You should do something as below

```
var priceProduct2 = priceProduct + (parseInt(width) + parseInt(length) * 30 );
```

Check out this example at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/Ygsrv/3/

Answer (score 0):

use this to parse the string as Integer-

```
parseInt(YourStringVar);
```